# Covert struct[int] to struct[any] in golang

Tags: go

```
type A[V any] struct {
  v V
}

func f(*A[any]) {
...
}

a := &A[int]{v: 1}

f(a) // error: cannot use a (variable of type *A[int]) as type *A[any] in argument to f
```

Is there a way that can convert `*A[int]` to `*A[any]` in Golang?

Please Help!

Comment: I guess you could [do this](https://go.dev/play/p/IjMKzOm3a9L) but what is your end goal here?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that can convert *A[int] to *A[any] in Golang?

No, there is no syntax or builtin for this stuff.

> Is there a way that can convert *A[int] to *A[any] in Golang?

Yes, write a function which does this (for each slice element).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot convert *A[int] to *A[any] without using some unsafe pointer conversions.

But you can change the function f to a generic function:

```golang
func f[V any](a *A[V]) {
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: What if `func f(arr []*A[V any]) {...}   f([]*A[any] {a: &A[int]{v: 1}, b: &A[string]{v: "xxx"}})`

Comment: no, you cannot do that in go, in fact that would not work in any language that I am aware of

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I was wondering how to define a `func` to accept a array that contains different data types?

Comment: Works fine in Typescript

Comment: Maybe generics is not what you are looking for here. A function getting a `[]any` or `[]someIntf` argument might be what you're looking for, but you still have to pass the correct type array. Alternatively, how about `func f(a ...interface{})`?

Comment: I showed you how to define a func that takes an array that contains different data types: with generics.  Before generics, it could not be done at all, unless the func took interface{} as the arg, allowing non-arrays too.